# Mac terminal : Sed regex, extracting part of a string

Tags: mac, terminal, regex, sed

I have a string , exactly a file path

`/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt`,

I need to extract the path of its folder ,

to get `/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/` .

Here is what I tried.

```
echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt " | sed  's@.*\(/.+\)@\1@p' 

/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt
```

I use regex capture group , try to capture group one `/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt`, and replace it with ,

Seems like that regex capture group have the effect of matching from the end to beginning.

then I will get

```
/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198
```

I have read [Sed regex, extracting part of a string in Mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424696/sed-regex-extracting-part-of-a-string-in-mac-terminal) again and again.

Hope get helped, amigo

Really want to get `/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/`,

`/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198` is not good.

any good idea?

Comment: `dirname "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first try doesn't work because the escape for `+` is missing

```
echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt " | sed  's@.*\(/.\+\)@\1@' 
/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt
```

(escapes for metacharacters can be avoided with `-r` or `-E` option, for Extended RE).

What you want is the dirname part, then just group the first part of the ER.

```
echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt " | sed  's@\(.*\)/.*@\1@' 
/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198
```

The quantifiers in `sed` are greedy, it means that when you ask to match a regex like `.*/.*`, the first `.*` will match **all** line until the end, because you asked to match anything`.` in any number`*`, and a `/` is anything in any number.

edit- If you want to read about regular expressions and sed, take a look
https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-0

Comment: The second regex is intuitive and nice. could you tell me why I try the first regex in my terminal `echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt" | sed  's@.*\(/.\+\)@\1@'`   result is `/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt`.                 not you showed above

Comment: @black_pearl This command line `echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt" | sed 's@.*\(/.\+\)@\1@'` you posted in the comment works, the output is `/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt`. Are you running this at MacOS (by the post title)? If yes, we are running different versions of `sed`, I'm on GNU/Linux. I don't know if all those unicode characters could affect the output. Could you try only with ASCII to see if it works `echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/198/file2017.txt" | sed 's@.*\(/.\+\)@\1@'` results in expected `/file2017.txt`

Comment: I run in a MacBook. No , still that. `echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/198/file2017.txt" | sed 's@.*\(/.\+\)@\1@'` , result is 
`/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/198/file2017.txt`. I should read your links, and try

Comment: This does work? `echo "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/198/file2017.txt" | sed -E 's@.*(/.+)@\1@'`. Try that with the unicode string too please, it should work. I ran in a FreeBSD VirtualBox vm and it worked, but it's language isn't properly configured.

Comment: got it ,  nice of u

Comment: It seems that backreference in MacOS belongs to ERE, it needs `-E` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
dirname "/Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/198/李宏毅-机器学习2017秋季.txt"
```